# Electron Remote Upgrade Issue

Tags: electron

I have a working Electron app which I wrote about two years ago. I'm not an employee of a company, but just some guy that wrote an app that a few people use to make the world a better place. Anyway, I need to make some changes to the app but my computer crashed a while back so I downloaded my old code from Github onto my new computer and started to get to work.  But immediately I found the app wouldn't work in the new 17.0.0 version of electron because the REMOTE module in Electron was deprecated and then removed in previous versions.  I tried to follow the instructions here... https://www.npmjs.com/package/@electron/remote?activeTab=readme to replace REMOTE with the new @electron/remote module.  I've had several problems, my most recent is:

JavaScript Error: Uncaught Exception: TypeError BrowserWindow is not a constuctor at app.createWindows (C:...\main.js:89:17).

I use the remote functionality (properties?) over 50 times in my app, including .dialogue, .getGlobal, .getCurrentWindow, and .BrowserWindow.getAllWindows

I'm not including my code here because I'm not really looking for a a coding solution (unless that's the easy/best/only thing I should do and you can give me a solution from the information I've written) but more general advice on what direction I should go to solve this problem. I'm a good programmer in a language that is not Electron, or JavaScript, or NodeJS! So, with the right instruction I can get by, but please be easy on me. (For example I get lost in the instructions for @electron/remote around the API Reference section.) Thanks for any help you can provide.

Mike

Comment: Well, this is a coding site, so you should break down your problem into smaller problems, look if there are solutions for those and if not, then ask specific questions here, including minimal code to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some big changes have been made to Electron over the past couple of years, especially with the use of `remote`. I would hate to say it but it looks like you are in for a bit of work to get it operational again.

You will want to look at [`ipcMain`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main), [`ipcRender`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer) and [`contextBridge`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge).

The inclusion of `webPreferences: {preload: ""}` in your [`new BrowserWindow()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) method plus the use of the above Electron methods will place you in a good starting position for safe, quick, thread seperated code.

See [Context Isolation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation) and [Inter-Process Communication](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) for more info.

PS: If you need a quick bit of code to get you going / give you an idea then let me know.

Comment: Thank you Dharman.  I was worried I might be missing something, but this will help me sleep knowing it's not me!  I'm working on converting all my Renderer SQLite calls to IPC them back to my main.js to do it there now.  Thanks again for taking the time to respond!
-Mike